# SVD-like matrix transformation (rank normal form)

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, svd, mathematica-8

I am implementing a research paper in MATLAB and have encountered a matrix transformation that I don't know how to get done in MATLAB.
Here it is,

```
P*L*Q = [I O]
```

where P,Q are transformation matrices, L is the given matrix, and I,O are identity and zero matrices respectively.

Can anyone help me get this done in MATLAB through some function or an algorithm so I can implement this through my code?

Comment: This is usually called "rank normal form" of a matrix; I added this term to the title.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the easiest way would be to use the in-build function svd.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

Comment: can you give me some hint at the algorithm that can be used to get this done if there is nothing built-in in matlab

Comment: The OP is not asking about SVD. Try to read more than three characters of the question.